# How can I get my drop-down to not open unless the li is hovered?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

For a while now I have stayed away from using `opacity` and `height` to animate drop-downs with css. My reason for this is due to them being activated without having the `li` hovered on.

What happens since the drop-down is not using `display: none;` to `display: block;` you can activate the drop-down underneath the `li` where the nested menu would show.

I was sick of using the same animation over and over again so I tried my best to prevent this but, sadly, the menu still does this. (It also seems to display the text in IE and Firefox on some monitors, not all)

Here is my css for the menu,

```
.subNav {
    width: 200px;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    transition: all 0.6s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.6s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.6s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.6s ease;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -100px;
    border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    top: 0;
}

ul.nav li:hover .subNav {
    min-height: 100px;
    height: auto;
    overflow: visible;
    background: #c1c1c1;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
```

Here is a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_JM/kQAcY/2/show/), remove show in url to see code, if you hover between the nav and div that is underneath it you will see how it opens. Is there anyway I can prevent this?

Screenshot of the text clipping, (not the problem since it is very random. I have this happen on my mac chrome but at work on my windows chrome seems to be fine. In firefox and IE on my computer at work does it while my coworkers is fine in firefox.)

[image: Text showing behind div]

Comment: `display:none` is missing

Comment: Display none is missing for a reason. In my question I stated I didn't use that method and the reason behind it is due to that technique kills the animation.

Comment: how about using webkit animation instead of transition that would do the same thing

Comment: or as i did in answer instead of making it invisible or remove it, just move it far away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The immediate fix to your problem is to use the `visibility` property.

This is a CSS2 property and therefore should work on all major browsers including full support back to IE8 (the main one you generally need to go back for), but also partial support for IE6+ according to http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/visibility

All you should need to add is:

`.subNav { visibility: hidden; }`
`ul.nav li:hover .subNav { visibility: visible; }`

and that should work how I am guessing you want it to work straight away.

Please note however, that there is a difference to `visibility` and `display`, and this still technically renders the subNav and allocates its defined space and position, however, *in this case* it doesn't matter due to the nature of the position of the other elements. Read more about the difference here: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp

Due to the positioning and render issues outlined above with `visibility` vs `display` this may not always be the correct solution and on other pages or in the future may push other elements out of alignment. Just take note of this.

Hope this answers your question.

GB.

Answer (score 2):

You should use visibility: hidden and visibility: visible on hover. :)
Don't use overflow:hidden for this purpose.

I've improved the animation by just saying: transition: opacity 0.6s ease; and added opacity:0; to the default state and opacity: 1; to hover state. With a little help from visibility hidden it all works fine!

http://jsfiddle.net/kQAcY/18/embedded/result/

```
.subNav {
    width: 200px;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    transition: opacity 0.6s ease;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.6s ease;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.6s ease;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.6s ease;
    -ms-transition: opacity 0.6s ease;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -100px;
    border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    top: 0;
}

ul.nav li:hover .subNav {
    //min-height: 100px;
    //height: auto;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    overflow: visible;
    background: #c1c1c1;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
```

Comment: Sadly that does not hide anything inside of the submenu just the background.

Comment: on the subnav add visibility:hidden on hover add visibility:visible;

Comment: This is the best option so far but the fade out animation is a bit glitchy, http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_Powell/kQAcY/11/.

Comment: i think you missed the point of question that is that hovering mouse not on a menu still tigers hover.. because subnav is hidden and still there which it needs to be for animation

Comment: Sorry for delay in marking it as right, been very busy at work. I marked Jamie's answer because it still preserved the animation. Thank you for all of your effort!

Answer (score 1):

There you go: http://jsfiddle.net/kQAcY/5/ . When isn't hovered, the `li` should have `overflow:hidden` so it can't  be triggered by his children `ul`, and when hovered, it will show the `overflow`.

Comment: This removes it form being activated outside of the `li`!! wohoo, but now it does not scroll back up, it lost the animation. Trust me man, I tried a lot on this one to work with the animation while not being activated. :/

Comment: Enjoy:P http://jsfiddle.net/kQAcY/7/ The problem was the padding. Even if you give it `height:0`, the padding still takes space. You only need to give `padding-top:10px` to first li, and `padding-bottom:10px` to last li item.

Answer (score 1):

`max-height` and `opacity` are able to be transitioned, so use these two properties to keep the transitions and not worry about anything showing. With overflow, the `:before` pseudo element isn't transitioned. **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kQAcY/16/)**

Also, if you add these two properties, you can prevent the hover from happening outside the #mainNav:

```
#mainNav {
    overflow: hidden;
}

#mainNav:hover {
    overflow: visible;
}

.subNav {
    width: 200px;
    //remove overflow: hidden;
    max-height: 0; /*replace height: 0*/
    font-size: 16px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    transition: all 0.6s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.6s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.6s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.6s ease;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -100px;
    border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    top: 0;
    opacity: 0; /* add opacity: 0*/
}


ul.nav li:hover .subNav {
    max-height: 500px; /* add max-height: any value larger than your dropdowns; replace min-height */
    background: #c1c1c1;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    opacity: 0.99; /* add opacity: 0.99 or 1 */
    //remove overflow: visible;
}
```

Comment: This will still be activated when you hover under the li.

Comment: Hadn't noticed that - I guess you'll have to add in overflow: hidden/visible

Comment: And that actually doesn't take care of it either. I think what's causing it is a gap between #body and #mainNav. So add 'overflow: hidden' to `#mainNav` and `overflow: visible` to `#mainNav:hover`. I've updated my answer to show this.

Answer (score 1):

i did what you wanted by adding `opacity` property and setting `top:-999999;` So when element isn't hovered then it won't be on screen and thus no unintentional hovering.

And no cancellation of animation either

http://jsfiddle.net/kQAcY/19/show/

http://jsfiddle.net/kQAcY/19/

```
.subNav {
    opacity:0;top:-9999px;
...
...
ul.nav li:hover .subNav {
    top:0px; opacity:1;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you increase your margin-top to 10px, This is at least a temp fix and hides the bit of text showing up prior to the hover state.

```
.subNav > li {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        margin-top: 10px;
        text-align: left;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, this is a temp fix for that problem but my main problem is the menu being activated without the `li` being hovered.